# Двойной клик при использовании .click в JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть элемент `label` с классом `radioContainer`, при клике на него должен раскрываться список `selectmenu` с классом `meal`, дело в том, что при клике происходить двойное выполнение колбэка, т.е `console.log('double')` выводит в консоль `double` два раза, из за этой проблемы не получается закрывать `selectmenu` если он уже открыт (для этого и создана переменная `selectStatus`);

Вот полный [проект](https://catinears.github.io/RepeatPaymentsForm/) с этим багом

---

P.S: Немного объясню, что тут в коде и для чего, дело в том, что на самом деле есть 2 `label` с одинаковым классом `radioContainer` с `selectmenu`'шками перед ними, но у первого присутствует класс `first`, и условие внутри `.click` проверяет наличие класса `first` у элемента по которому кликнули, если есть - открыть первый список, нету - второй.

```
let selectStatus = true;

$('label.radioContainer').click(function() {
    console.log('double');
    selectStatus = !selectStatus;

    if($(this).hasClass('first') && selectStatus) {
        $('.meal:first').selectmenu('open');
    } else if(selectStatus){
        $('.meal:not(:first)').selectmenu('open');
    }
}); // end click
```

Answer (score 0):

Пара исправлений нужно сделать и будет работать.
1) Класс `first` у вас не в том месте. У вас он в тэге `<span>` а надо в родительский узел его добавить, а именно в `<label class="radioContainer first">`. Это для того чтобы ваш `$(this)` правильно отрабатывал. Иначе он никогда не нашел бы класс `first`
2) Немного модифицировал ваш `event`:

```
$('label.radioContainer').change(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    let menu = $(this).hasClass('first') ? $('.meal:first') : $('.meal:not(:first)');
    menu.hasClass('ui-selectmenu-button-open') ? menu.selectmenu('close') : menu.selectmenu('open');
 }); // end click
```